# Quick way to replicating old matrix to new one

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

e.g I have the original matrix (m) looks like this one

```
1 2
3 4
```

Then I use n = padarray(m,[oldMatrixRow,OldMatrixColumn]); I will have

```
x x x x x x
x x x x x x 
x x 1 2 x x 
x x 3 4 x x 
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

The point here is that I would want my new matrix look like this

```
1 2 1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4 3 4
1 2 1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4 3 4
1 2 1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4 3 4
```

Is there any smart way to do that ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `repmat`

```
B = repmat(A,m,n)
```

where `A` is the matrix you want to repeat, and `m` and `n` define the dimensions of how it is repeated

In your case here, call your original matrix `A` and use

```
B = repmat(A,3,3)
```

to get your desired output

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you just want to repeat your matrix a number of times the easy way would be to use repmat:

```
m = [1 2;3 4];
n = repmat(m,3,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alternative solution:

```
kron(ones(3), [1 2; 3 4])
```